# Why is this function valid for $x>1$?

Tags: logarithms

*The question is* $$ 4^{\log_2(\ln(x))} = \ln(x)-\ln(x)^2+1$$
*Upon simplifying we'd get*
\begin{align}
&\phantom{{}\implies {}} 2\ln(x)^2-\ln(x)-1=0 \\
 &\implies \ln(x)=1 \text{ or }\ln(x)={-1 \over 2} \\
 &\implies x=e\text { or } x=e^{{-1\over2}}
\end{align}
*I understand that upon putting $e^{-1/2}$ into the original expression, it doesn't give a meaningful result; but is there a better way to explain this?*

Comment: The main gist of it is that the simplification you use on the left-hand side at the very beginning gets rid of a restriction that $\ln(x) > 0.$ So although the original equation being satisfied implies that $x$ is one of the two values we get at the end, it is not the case that $x$ being one of the two values implies that the equation is satisfied unless you reintroduce the restriction $\ln(x) > 0 \Leftrightarrow x > 1.$

Comment: Terribly sorry. I thought it had something to do with the range of the function. Sleep-deprived me forgot to consider that $ln(x)$ has to be positive for the function to be defined for real values.

Comment: When $x$ is greater than $1$, we have $4^{\log_2(\ln x)}=(\ln x)^2$. It turns out that the expression on the RHS is defined for all $x>0$ (not just $x>1$), whereas the LHS is only defined for $x>1$. This similar to how $\frac{x}{x}=1$ for all $x \ne 0$, but the RHS is actually defined for all $x$. This means that it is possible to get *extraneous solutions* (solutions that solve $2(\ln x)^2-\ln(x)-1=0$, but not the original equation).

Comment: @Infinity207 Don't worry about it, I do plenty of dumb things on here when I haven't slept. Glad we got it all figured out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is $$4^{\log_2(\ln(x))}$$ only defined if $$\ln(x)>0$$ and this is the case if $$x>1$$